# D'où vient le nom commun « flanquée » ?

Tags: étymologie, noms

En réalisant le transcript de [API Platform Conference 2022](https://youtu.be/4hSOltkbMWE?t=1240) je suis tombé pour la première fois sur le mot *flanquée* utilisé comme un nom commun. Au vu du contexte j'ai d'abord pensé à une mauvaise prononciation de *palanquée*, mais après une recherche rapide il apparaît que ce mot existe bien :

- > ceux-ci doivent exécuter leurs chants, leurs danses devant une flanquée d'œilletons sans vie.
  > [Philomag.com](https://www.philomag.com/articles/tout-ce-qui-etait-directement-vecu-sest-eloigne-dans-une-representation)
- > on retrouve une flanquée de filtres à effet, façon Instagram. [Korben](https://korben.info/pimagic-retouche-et-instagramisation-en-ligne-de-vos-photos.html)
- > la Bourse de New York va accueillir une flanquée de nouveaux venus. [Lesechos.fr](https://www.lesechos.fr/industrie-services/tourisme-transport/treize-ans-apres-sa-creation-airbnb-fait-le-grand-saut-boursier-1272634)
- > Entre deux séries, trois films et une flanquée d’animes, Netflix enrichit son catalogue. [Jeuxvideo.com](https://www.jeuxvideo.com/news/1691406/perdez-vos-kilos-en-trop-avec-ce-programme-fitness-sur-netflix.htm)

Cependant je n'arrive à le trouver dans aucun dictionnaire. D'où vient-il ?

Comment: Excellente question. Je suis, moi aussi, surpris de ne rien trouver dans les dictionnaires alors qu'il me semble que j'emploie ce mot à l'oral depuis toujours...

Comment: @jiliagre merci pour le témoignage ! A-t-il un usage spécifique ou est-il employé comme un simple synonyme de « multitude » ?

Comment: Il a probablement débuté en étant associé à des gifles ou des coups puis s'est généralisé.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aucun dictionnaire ne semble en effet indiquer un usage substantif de ***flanquée***.

J'y vois une dérivation du verbe populaire [***flanquer***](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/flanquer/1), qui signifie *Jeter, envoyer, mettre brutalement ou brusquement quelqu'un ou quelque chose quelque part* d'où par exemple ***flanquer des gifles*** évoluant en ***une flanquée de gifles***.

> *Saddam Hussein s'est pris une flanquée de bombes pour des raisons aussi surréalistes que celles pour lesquelles l'OTAN a bombardé la Yougoslavie.*

On retrouve un peu le même phénomène avec *[bordée](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bord%C3%A9e)* (**une bordée de jurons**, de coups, etc.) et on peut observer que ***bord*** et ***flanc*** sont sémantiquement proches.

Une flopée d'autres synonymes de *beaucoup/grand nombre* sont construits suivant ce modèle :

Une *[palanquée](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/palanqu%C3%A9e)*, [volée](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vol%C3%A9e), [flopée](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/flop%C3%A9e), [tripotée](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tripot%C3%A9e), ([tétra](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%A9trachi%C3%A9e)/méga)[chiée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/6120), [tapée](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tap%C3%A9e), [bardée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/74794), [trifouillée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/74744), [pelletée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/80748), et les rares ou oubliés [tinée](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tin%C3%A9e), [tirée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/19914),  [pétée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/55858), [potée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/18147), [secouée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/39010), [suée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/9843), [trolée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/9844)/[trâlee](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trol%C3%A9e/1)<sup>1</sup>, [chariotée](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/74780),  ...

> *Une **volée** de coups de poing*.

La proximité phonétique de *flanquée* avec *palanquée*, signalée dans la question, a peut-être aussi joué un rôle dans la genèse de ce mot.

Sans que ce soit contradictoire avec la première hypothèse, on peut aussi considérer que ***flanquée*** est une dérivation du mot ***flanc***, le suffixe *-ée* indiquant alors une quantité, un contenu, une valeur comme dans *poing* → *poignée*, *bouche* → *bouchée*, *jour* → *journée* et donc *flanc* → *flanquée*.

La première apparition de ***flanquée*** comme substantif date de 1753 et suit certainement ce modèle. Elle est rapportée en 1874 dans la *Revue des deux mondes* qui cite une lettre de Montesquieu reprise en 1924 dans *Le chevalier d'Aydie et mademoiselle Aïssé*, Emile Dusolier :
[image]

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Encore courant au Québec.</sub>

Comment: Merci pour la piste ! J’accepterai cette réponse dans les prochains jours en l’absence de source.

Comment: *Flanquée* pourrait-il être une sorte de fusion de *flopée* et de *palanquée* ;) ?

Comment: @XouDo Oui, on peut imaginer des pelletées d'hypothèses ;-)